# Why my graph is wrong in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, ember.js, ember-charts

I am using this chart without bar data [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Frr.png): [charts-time-series Link](http://opensource.addepar.com/ember-charts/#/time-series)

Here is how it looks in Chrome
[image]

And here is how it looks in Firefox
[image]

Here is the chart in chrome without 'fill: none' property. The component set this property correctlty:[image]

The line has a little over 8000 points. There are no errors in console.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the CSS that styles that chart:

```
.line {
  fill: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It seems that the chart already set's this property as you suggested. I removed it for a bit and here is what I've got SEE IMAGE 3.

Comment: Without any code it's hard to determine what's causing this. In Chrome you can right-click in the dark section of your chart, select the "Inspect" option and find out the element which is missing the `fill: none;` rule.

Comment: It's also possible that you have way too many points in your chart. Maybe try reducing the number of plotted points https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/980/how-do-i-reduce-the-number-of-data-points-in-a-series

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick answers. The code is very simple [code]{{time-series-chart
         lineData=data
         selectedInterval=selectedInterval
        }}[/code]. Maybe is just a chrom bug as in firefox works perfect.